# What word should I use instead of 'having a word'?

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say my shirt has been ruined by a dry-cleaner and I am very furious about it, so I am going back there. My friend asks me where am I going.

I can say

> I am going back to the dry cleaner's **to have a word with him** about my t-shirt.

What I want to say is that I am going there to criticize or to yell at him for ruining my shirt, To say '**to have a word with him**' seems very polite and using **confront** seems very violent, but I might be wrong.

What is the correct/more appropriate word here for  **to have a word**?

Comment: "Confront" actually does not always mean a violent meeting or encounter, even though it can be used that way. You would definitely find native speakers who use it for this situation. However, in this instance the idiom "to give him a piece of my mind" would fit nicely.

Comment: If you think *have a word with* is too circumspect/polite, and *confront/remonstrate/etc.* are too confrontational, you might consider [see about](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/see+about) *to take care of, look after; investigate; enquire into*. Often heard as *"We'll see about that!"* meaning *I don't approve of 'that', and will take steps to prevent it happening.*

Comment: @JonathanGarber: Confront is always quite aggressive, but it is not always violent.

Comment: @Matt: An excellent point. I would be cautious about using "aggressive", but as you say it certainly does not imply violence necessarily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To have a word with him** would be correct in the context. While it is typically used to mean *to have a (brief) private conversation with him*, it's also a common euphemism for exactly what you want to say.

A similar phrase that is possibly more appropriate is *to have words with*. Note the change from *a word* to *words*. This expression typically implies a harsher, more critical tone.

Comment: _To have a talk with him_ or simply _to talk with him_ would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, **have a word** is completely appropriate.

A slightly more formal way to say the same thing would be:

> I am going back to dry cleaner's to **complain** to him about *what he did to* my t-shirt.

Answer (score 3):

“To have a word with him” is a correct phrase, but apparently less expressive than you desire.  A few alternative verbs that spring to mind include
• *[upbraid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upbraid#Verb)*, “To criticize severely” or “To reprove severely; to rebuke; to chide” etc.
• *[remonstrate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remonstrate#Verb)*, “To object; to express disapproval”
• *[reproach](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reproach#Verb)*, “To [criticize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criticize#Verb) or [rebuke](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebuke#Verb) someone”
•  *admonish, berate, [castigate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/castigate#Verb), censure, chastise,
[excoriate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excoriate#Verb)* and many more synonyms, as found in [Wikisaurus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus%3areprehend) and in [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=rebuke) or in [dico](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=rebuke&send=Look+it+up)

Idiomatic *[flea in one's ear](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flea_in_one%27s_ear)* also is possible:  “I'm off to the dry cleaner's to put a flea in his ear about what he did to my t-shirt.” Also *[pick a bone with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+bone+to+pick+with)*: “I'm going to go pick a bone with that dry cleaner about what he did to my t-shirt.”